# asp contentPlaceHolder tag inside script tags?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a master page with some script in the head:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function example() {
        //some code here
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

I would like to have some way to add to the script tag from child pages as if I could put `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ... />` inside the script of the master page like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function example() {
        //some code here
    }
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="Script" />
    </script>
</head>
```

I do not necessarily need to use `<asp:contentPlaceHolder />` so something of the same nature would be OK. Any help is good help!

EDIT:
VDWWD's answer worked. if anyone is looking for vb.net code as I was, the conversion is fairly simple:

this is the code for the master page:

```
Partial Class Site
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    Public Property JavaScriptBlock() As String
        Get
            Return m_JavaScriptBlock
        End Get
        Set
            m_JavaScriptBlock = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_JavaScriptBlock As String
End Class
```

in the master page you can put `<%= JavaScriptBlock %>` anywere you want the code to be

and in code of the child pages:

```
Dim Master As PurelyHR_Web = Page.Master
Master.JavaScriptBlock = "Code From Child Page!"
```

Comment: It is not very clear why. There are lots of ways you can add javascript to a page, using `ScriptManager` for example. You can also write out the script block in the child page since it will become the same page from a client perspective.

Comment: the script needs to be in the master page because it is the same through all the child pages but there is just a small section of script that changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by creating a public property on the Master Page

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string JavaScriptBlock { get; set; }
```

On the aspx of the Master place this for testing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('<%= JavaScriptBlock %>');
</script>
```

Then in any child page you can now reference the property.

```
Site master = (Site)Page.Master;
master.JavaScriptBlock = "Code from child page";
```

Comment: Excellent! this worked, I was using vb.net but no worries, I just converted your code to vb and it works thanks a bunch